# Table field type and length contradicting(?) Timestamp(6)WithLocalTimeZone and Length=11

Tags: excel, datetime, format, timestamp-with-timezone

Good day all,

I'm working on an Excel file that should deliver a curtain output to be transferred via FTP to be processed with a partner.

My partner has provided the table definitions and I'm running into an ambiguous definition:

A date field is listed as type `Timestamp(6)WithLocalTimeZone`, of which I understand is to be formatted as `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.nnnnnn +xx:yy`. This does make enough sense on it's own, but the length mentioned in the table definition is 11, and the type format exceeds that by double.

Please help me understand how to format this date and time according to the table definitions. Thanks in advance